# Can I estimate the confidence intervals when fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient?

Tags: mixed-model, confidence-interval, covariance-matrix

I have run model selection for linear mixed effect models with random intercepts, built with lme4 package in R. The top model contains one continuous variable (A), 2 categorical variables (B and C) and the interaction between the categorical variables (BC). I am trying to predict a continuous variable (Y). The formula is: Y ~ A + B + C + BC + (1|random1) + (1|random2) Unfortunately, the top model gives me the warning that "the fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient".

I have understood the reason behind the warning (the problem is in the interaction between B (that has 2 levels) and C (that has 3 levels). There, not all the combinations have data, leading to the dropping of 1 column in the variance-covariance matrix. This, in turn, leads to the fact that confidence intervals are not calculated for the coefficients of the model.

My question is, is it possible to estimate somehow the confidence intervals? Is there a "manual" way or it is simply not possible? I must stress that the top model I present here is the result of the selection after the full inspection among a larger set of variables (also variable D and E), so I have to stick to that model.

I tried to look for answers in other posts such as this, but I mainly found explanation of why the warning appears and how it may affect predictions. I also went deeper into the variance-covariance matrix concept and theory, but I still cannot find an answer. I did find one possible way, with the function confint() from the "stats" package. But I am not sure about the robustness of the output since the variance covariance matrix is rank deficient and thus the Confidence intervals should not be computed.

Can someone help me to clarify and point out possible solutions?
Thank you very much!